# Can't get removal of view to animate

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a `VStack` where I have a title above some other views. The title is shown/hidden based on the value of an `@Published` variable from an environment object. Ideally, when the title should be hidden, I want it to transition by fading out and moving the views below it in the `VStack` up. However, what actually happens is it just disappears immediately and moves the rest of the views up without animation. How can I fix this?

```
struct MyView: View {
@EnvironmentObject var modelController: MyModelController

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            title()
            //..other views here
        }
    }

    @ViewBuilder
    func title() -> some View {
        if let currentPage = modelController.currentPage,
           currentPage >= 6 {
            EmptyView()
        } else {
            Text("Create Event")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use the `.transition()` modifier to tell the system that you want to animate when the view appears or disappears. Additionally, I don't think you need to return `EmptyView` when you want to hide the title.

```
@ViewBuilder
func title() -> some View {
    if modelController.currentPage ?? 0 < 6 {
        Text("Create Event")
            .transition(.opacity)
    }
}
```

I've used the `opacity` transition but it's a very customizable modifier, and you can pass an asymmetric transition that does different animations on insert and removal. I would suggest googling it or looking at the documentation to learn more about it.

Comment: This only worked when I applied animation to it as well. Not sure why

Comment: Yes, I believe you will have to update the value of `currentPage` in the closure of a `withAnimation` function call.

Answer (score 1):

Your code snapshot is not testable, but try the following

```
VStack {
    title()
    //..other views here
}
.animation(.default, value: modelController.currentPage)   // << here !!
```